# Stopping a Body (travelling at the speed of light)

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

While, I read that if a body accelerates to the speed of light would have an infinite mass and therefore, infinite energy would be required to maintain the speed.

A question popped up in my mind:

Assuming we've a body traveling at the speed of light (and having infinite mass), how difficult would it be to stop that body? What if it collides with a planet, would it stop or will it continue moving?

EDIT: Only infinite source (or tremendous source) of energy would be required to reach the speed of light. Once reached at that speed, I guess, nothing would try to stop it in a vacuum (except colliding or gravitational bending).

Comment: Mainstream physics in this context means that a massive body has _finite_ (rest) mass and speed _less_ than the speed of light in vacuum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would not have infinite mass. Relativistic mass is device used to introduce beginners into relativity. Mass is invariant (doesn't change due to reference frame) in more advanced relativistic studies. Aside from that, one does not merely need infinite energy to reach c. One also needs infinite time. Therefore, your question is if we wait until infinity is over and then we do the impossible (moving at c) (it is not possible for something with mass, but it is REQUIRED for something without mass), what happens? Physics can not answer such a question because you are asking what happens to a system if we ignore is rules.

Also, $E = mc^2$. Wherever you are getting this energy, the mass there must be infinite. An infinite mass in a finite space would form a black hole.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks. I had forgot that infinite mass would form a blackhole.

Comment: What do you mean by infinite time though?

Comment: Let's imagine that you push on a block. The next second you push harder, then harder, then harder... That way you can overcome the "relativistic mass" It would take infinite time to get to infinity, unless you plan on doing it all at once. If you do, though, the other reasons would take care of the question.

Comment: Do we call that acceleration? Sorry for asking too many annoying questions but I am merely a mid-schooler.

Comment: @Areeb If it gets faster... By overcome "relativistic mass" I mean keep it accelerating at a constant pace.

Comment: @Areeb Also "Since the net applied force is equal to the rate of change of momentum and the work done is equal to the change in energy, it would take an infinite time and an infinite amount of work to accelerate an object to the speed of light. (Sorry, Captain Kirk. We can't give you warp speed!)"

Comment: Well, when discussing "infinite energy" all bets are off, and that's also impossible, but in general, a super-accelerated (very close to the speed of light) object wouldn't form a black hole cause it's not the right type of mass.   more on that here:  http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/BlackHoles/black_fast.html

Comment: @userLTK I didn't say that a super accelerated object would form a black hole. I started my answer by saying that mass is invariant.

Comment: @userLTK I said that the source of his energy would form a black hole (i.e. a battery with infinite charge or something of the sort)

Comment: Ah, my apologies.   You're right.

Comment: @Jimmy360 what do you mean, no warp speed? I have seen the movies - they do it all the time!

Answer (score 2):

Infinite energy would be required to reach that speed - not to maintain it. But you can never reach the speed of light... only ever get close. Like they do in the new LHC - individual protons getting energies in the TeV range. At these energies, they have a gamma of about 7000 - meaning they have 7000 times their "rest mass". That's heavy, but nowhere near "infinite".

By definition, it is impossible for massive particles to reach the speed of light. Particles without mass (photons) do it routinely - and when they hit the Earth, we call it "sunlight".

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will wait for more answers to clear the confusion. And, then accordingly choose the wisest answer.